# how to convert a windows phone application to panorama app?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-7.1.1

I have a screen in my application which has GPS details. Now I am thinking I will add a map to this page. So I want to display this map when user swipes from left to right .I feel panorama app will be good for this. Any idea how do I convert this to panorama app ?

Answer (score 0):

Create a new project and select the Panorama Template.

Then add the UI code of your old app, add as the Panorama item of new project. You can any no of Panorama items. Check this [Panorama Control link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsphonetrainingcourse_usingpivotandpanoramacontrols_topic4.aspx)